# SharePoint 2010 My Sites versus custom code for Social Networking / Micro-Blogging

Tags: .net, sharepoint, social-networking, microblogging

What kind of features does the upcoming SharePoint 2010 have in regards to functionality that is like those found in:

FriendFeed, Twitter, Google Wave?
Flickr or Digg (tagging and voting)?

How much of this do you get "for free" with SP 2010 or would you still have to code it all yourself? Any one know what that have added to My Sites? Anything really too difficult for a 2 person senior dev team to code up in 6 weeks?

I'm trying to get a good sense of this before I weight in at some future discussions at work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blog posts relating to this from SPC '09:

- [SharePoint 2010 My Sites, social networking architectural](http://hermansberghem.blogspot.com/2009/10/sharepoint-2010-my-sites-social.html)
- [SPC: Overview of Social Computing in SharePoint 2010](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2010/archive/2009/10/20/spc-overview-of-social-computing-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)
- [MySite and Social Networking Architecture](http://blogs.inetium.com/blogs/spc/archive/2009/10/20/mysite-and-social-networking-architecture.aspx)

There will be tagging and rating so there's a chance custom development won't be required for what you need.

I strongly recommend signing up for the [SP2010 beta](http://sharepoint2010.microsoft.com/try-it/Pages/Trial.aspx) which will be released late November and have a look yourself if at all possible. (Make note of the [system requirements](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2009/05/11/announcing-sharepoint-server-2010-preliminary-system-requirements.aspx) and I understand 8GB of RAM is required for a production server - you may be able to get away with less if you can put up with disk thrashing.)

Also keep an eye on the [SharePoint 2010 section of SharePointDevWiki](http://sharepointdevwiki.com/display/sp2010/SharePoint+2010+Development+Home).

Comment: Any news on this yet? I'm scanning the Google news site for items. Where else should I go look for breaking news on this? Are all the features know as of this morning?

Comment: Thanks. This is awesome. Helps me with my SP strategy. +1 and answer